# Update Google Analytics Tracking Code with Analytical gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, tracking, analytical

I'm using the "Analytical" gem in my Ruby on Rails application but it's not working anymore because I have to update the Google Analytics Tracking Code. How can I do that?
There is the link with the update to do: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using this [jkrall/analytical](https://github.com/jkrall/analytical) gem, right?

I've looked into the google_universal.rb module (lib/analytical/google_universal.rb), and saw that the code is for Universal Analytics. At this time, Universal Analytics [doesn't offer support for display advertising](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/).

If you're using an older version of the analytical gem that is using google analytics, then you should be able to replace the code there.